# Does GTM really load all tags Asyncronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-tag-manager, web-performance

One of the big benefits and features of Google Tag Manager from [their website](https://marketingplatform.google.com/intl/en_uk/about/tag-manager/features/):

> Fire tags asynchronously, so they load independently from one another and don’t slow down your pages.

Consider this type of synchronous tag usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="www.example.com/third-party-tag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //run some function from third-party-tag.js
</script>
```

The external js must be loaded synchronously otherwise the second script will usually fail. If you put this directly into the page HTML (no GTM) the js loads synchronously and the second script works.

If you add both script tags into one Custom HTML tag in GTM, it also still works. And there's no 'async' attributes being added that I can see. How is this possible...

1. Is it the simple and obvious answer: Google Tag Manager is NOT
   loading the external js script asynchronously as it claims?
2. Have I misunderstood what GTM's claim means? e.g. the retrieval and
   preparation of the custom HTML snippet (tag) is asynchronous, but
   once the HTML is added to the DOM, all the normal rules
   apply to those tags.

Thanks for any advice!
p.s. refactoring the snippet to a 'better' approach is not in scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that just because a script is loaded asynchronously it still can block the main thread. All async does is direct the browser to NOT block downloading other requests while the script is being downloaded. Here is a good explanation,

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/html-defer-async

With async, the file gets downloaded asynchronously and then executed as soon as it’s downloaded.

With defer, the file gets downloaded asynchronously but executed only when the document parsing is completed.

I prefer to "defer" scripts if possible.

Comment: thanks. In the case I'm looking at the execution is pretty lightweight so its only really the script download that's a concern in terms of measurable blocking time.